# Laravel 5.7: Custom Validation Rule. Can't use class injected to constructor

Tags: php, laravel

I made new Rule via `php artisan make:rule` to do some custom validation by performing a query.

So inside the Rule I made a constructor and injected repository as I used to do dozens of times everywhere across the app.

```
class UniqueWishListNameByUser implements Rule
{
    private $wishListRepository;

    public function __construct(
        WishListRepository $wishListRepository
    ) {
        $this->wishListRepository = $wishListRepository;
    }
}
```

However in the `passes` method I can't use the injected class.

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
```

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Rules\UniqueWishListNameByUser::__construct(), 0 passed in
>   /home/vagrant/code/ios-portal/app/Http/Requests/Frontend/WishList/CreateWishListRequest.php
>   on line 31 and exactly 1 expected

This is because when I call the rule, it expects me to inject the class by myself.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            new UniqueWishListNameByUser(), // <--- here no args.
        ],
    ];
}
```

Should I inject the class somewhere else or should I invoke repository class by calling `app()->make()` which I don't want to do, unless I have to.

Am I missing something?

edit:

Below code works but I want to use dependency injection instead, how?

```
$wishlistRepository = app()->make(WishListRepository::class);

$exists = $wishlistRepository
    ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->where('customer_uuid', auth()->user()->defaultCustomer->uuid)
    ->where('name', $value)
    ->exists();
```

Comment: Have you tried withoud the `()` at the end? `new UniqueWishListNameByUser`

Comment: Yes, same result.

Answer (score 7):

You can inject the custom rule in `rules` method of the form request, as in:

```
public function rules(UniqueWishListNameByUser $unique)
{
    return [
        'name' => [
            'required',
            'string',
            $unique
        ],
    ];
}
```

From Laravel's [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation):

> You may type-hint any dependencies you need within the `rules` method's signature. They will automatically be resolved via the Laravel service container.

Comment: I thought that your issue was that a class you're injecting in custom rule's consturctor is not being resolved, and you looked for a way to make it happen, without "invoking repository class by calling app()->make()".

Comment: If `WishListRepository` is to be resolved from a type-hint in custom rule's constructor's the rule needs to be resolved from a container too. And one of the places where it can be done is `rules` method. Please let me know if I didn't get right what you were asking about.